# StylePaneFormatFilter modify styles to display custom styles

Tags: xml, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using openxml and c# to try to generate a document with some styles in it, styles generated in styles.xml .

I want these custom styles to be displayed in the Styles pane in Word for the user.

I believe the correct way to do this is to use the settings file and use the StylePaneFormatFilter to set these styles.

However I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have tried the following code to add the StylePaneFormatFilter to the document using openxml

```
 public void SetDocumentSettings(WordprocessingDocument document)
        {
            if (document.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart == null)
            {
                DocumentSettingsPart settingsPart = document.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>();
                settingsPart.Settings = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Settings(
                     new StylePaneFormatFilter()
                     {
                             CustomStyles = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true)
                     }
                );
                settingsPart.Settings.Save();
            }
        }
```

It generates the following xml in the settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<w:settings xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

<w:stylePaneFormatFilter w:customStyles="true"/>

</w:settings>
```

however when i try to validate the xml i get the following error :

Error Description: The 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:customStyles' attribute is not declared.ErrorType: SchemaNode: DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.StylePaneFormatFilterPath: /w:settings[1]/w:stylePaneFormatFilter[1]Part: /word/settings.xml

can someone help me understand what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Will the result open (or open and repair), even if the tool you're using doesn't validate? I looked in a settings.xml of a document and see no difference in the *syntax* for this attribute - just many more attributes.

Comment: FWIW however I don't think this does what you're looking for. If you open the "Manage Styles" dialog box in Word (from the Styles pane) you'll see a "Recommended" tab. Everything in this list will display in the pane unless "Hide until used" or "Hide" has been activated. And these are part of the *style definition* of each style.